# Python cannot connect to DB on XAMPP

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, xampp

I got a python file from another pc, and that pc is using mySQL to be the db. Now I'm trying to use db on XAMPP, but it seems some errors happened. I tried to use Anaconda Prompt to check the problem that shows below:

**Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\xampp\htdocs\distest.py", line 48, in <module**(ignore me)**>

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',

File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 311, in **init**

self.encoding = charset_by_name(self.charset).encoding

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encoding'**

I've imported something about connection between python and mySQL:

```
import pymysql
```

and this is line 48 in python file:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', 
                       user='root',
                       passwd='', 
                       db='test1', 
                       charset='utf8_general_ci', 
                       cursorclass = pymysql.cursors.SSCursor)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Change the `charset` to `utf8mb4` Maybe the problem is solved

Comment: The original charset is utf8mb4, and it also failed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot connect as `root`. You must use a different account.

Ideally you would create an account for the application with just the permissions it needs, as this is best practice.

Comment: I also have a php file for connect to db, and that set as root is connect successfully.